# Modifying emularor/device list of visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vs-extensibility, vspackage, mpf

I am using Managed Package Framework (MPF) to create custom language service.
I want to add few emulators/devices in "Start" Combobox, for example

[image: VS - emulators]

How can I do that?

**Update 1:**

After some research, I came to know that you need to extend an abstract class **DebugLaunchProviderBase**.

But now I am again stuck with how to register this class with visual studio, so it can list my targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MPF_proj, then you will have to implement interface [IVsProjectCfgDebugTargetSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsprojectcfgdebugtargetselection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your ProjectConfig.cs.